# Stop scroll events for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController inside my ViewController. I have four views in my PageViewController. I want that the view should not scroll on the first view for right side scrolling and for fourth view for left side scrolling. How do I do that? Basically I need a methods like `(BOOL)scrollViewShouldScroll:`

I have tried using `scrollViewDidBeganDragging` and set contentOffset property, set `panGestureRecognizer`'s enabled to `false/true` but it does stop the scroll but out of luck.

Comment: Do you want this:   disabled <== [0]...[4] ==>  diseabled  ?

Comment: Yes exactly but it's [0]...[3] but no issues with that. @Masterfego how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've created two ViewController:

- **RootViewController:** where I manage the UIPageViewController
- **DataViewcontroller**: where I display what I want ( the page for us)

  ```
  class RootViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
  {
    var pageData:[String] = [] // where I store images names

  }
  ```

Implement these 2 methods:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

  if !viewController.isKindOfClass(DataViewController) // Specify your type
  {
    return nil
  }

    var index:Int = indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
  if index == 0
  {
    return nil
  }
  else if index == NSNotFound
  {
    return nil
  }

  index--
  return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}
```

.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

  if !viewController.isKindOfClass(DataViewController)  // Specify your type
  {
    return nil
  }

  var index:Int = indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
  if index == NSNotFound
  {
    return nil
  }

  index++   
  if index == self.pageData.count 
  {
    return nil
  }     

  return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

Personnal functions:

```
func indexOfViewController(viewController: DataViewController) -> Int
{
  return find(pageData, viewController.dataObject)!
}
```

.

```
func viewControllerAtIndex( index: Int) -> DataViewController! {
  if pageData.count == 0 || index >= pageData.count {
    return nil
  }

  var dataVC:DataViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DataViewController") as! DataViewController
  dataVC.dataObject = pageData[index] as String

  return dataVC
}
```

Comment: have you tested your code. I have already tried that and it's not working. Returning nil just stop showing any view controller but does not stop scroll events.

Comment: This code works, it's actually what I use in a app published in app store, a give you a part of my code to give you inspiration. You have to focus on the first two data source methods: **func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?** and **func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?**
You can post you code

Comment: What I want is when you scroll left on fourth screen it should do nothing. It should not show me black screen of my parent view. The view should stay stagnant.

Comment: @Masterfego what meteors need is to just pause listening to scrolling events until for example a certain Boolean variable is true. The start listening to scrolling events again. But controlling the view controllers in before and after just shows a black screen in the scroll after and when the Boolean variable is true you need to go back first then next again to make the user continue with the new view controllers.